# Encoding a list column to the legend of a plot

Tags: python, pandas, data-visualization, altair

Apologies in advance, I am not sure how to word this question best:

I am working with a large dataset, and I would like to plot Latitude and Longitude where the colour of the points (actually the opacity) is encoded to a 'FeatureType' column binded to the legend. This way I can use the legend to highlight on my map various features I am looking for.

[Here is a picture of my map and legend so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpB0W.png)

The problem is that in my dataset, the FeatureType column is a list of features that can be found there (i.e arch, bridge, etc..).

How can I make it so that the point shows up for both arch, and bridge. At the moment it creates its own category of (arch,bridge etc.), leading to over 300 combinations of about 20 different FeatureTypes.

The dataset can be found at http://atlantides.org/downloads/pleiades/dumps/pleiades-locations-latest.csv.gz

N.B: I am using altair/pandas

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd
from vega_datasets import data


df = pd.read_csv ('C://path/pleiades-locations.csv') 

alt.data_transformers.enable('json')

countries = alt.topo_feature(data.world_110m.url, 'countries')

selection = alt.selection_multi(fields=['featureType'], bind='legend')

brush = alt.selection(type='interval', encodings=['x'])

map = alt.Chart(countries).mark_geoshape(
    fill='lightgray',
    stroke='white'
).project('equirectangular').properties(
    width=500,
    height=300
)

points = alt.Chart(df).mark_circle().encode(
    alt.Latitude('reprLat:Q'),
    alt.Longitude('reprLong:Q'),
    alt.Color('featureType:N'),
    tooltip=['featureType','timePeriodsKeys:N'],
    opacity=alt.condition(selection, alt.value(1), alt.value(0.0))
).add_selection(
    selection)

(map + points)
```

Comment: No one will be able to answer unless they are presented with some sample data, an expected output diagram, or a little bit of code they are working on.

Comment: Sorry!, Thank you, is that a bit better?

Comment: I think it will be easier to organize and categorize duplicate strings by breaking down the target column string into non-duplicate strings, creating a recombined string, and then adding it to the original data frame.`tmp = df['featureType'].str.split(',',expand=True); type_str = set(list(set(tmp[0]))+list(set(tmp[1]))+list(set(tmp[2]))+list(set(tmp[3])))`

Comment: Thanks, that splits up the column correctly into seperate columns, how would I then set up my legend such that it would check all of the columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible for Altair to generate the labels you want from your current column format. You will need to turn your comma-separated string labels into lists and then [explode the column](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) so that you get one row per item in the list:

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd
from vega_datasets import data

alt.data_transformers.enable('data_server')

df = pd.read_csv('http://atlantides.org/downloads/pleiades/dumps/pleiades-locations-latest.csv.gz')[['reprLong', 'reprLat', 'featureType']]
df['featureType'] = df['featureType'].str.split(',')
df = df.explode('featureType')

countries = alt.topo_feature(data.world_110m.url, 'countries')

world_map = alt.Chart(countries).mark_geoshape(
    fill='lightgray',
    stroke='white')

points = alt.Chart(df).mark_circle(size=10).encode(
    alt.Latitude('reprLat:Q'),
    alt.Longitude('reprLong:Q'),
    alt.Color('featureType:N', legend=alt.Legend(columns=2)))

world_map + points
```

[image]

Note that having this many entries in the legend is not meaningful since the colors are repeated. The interactivity would help with that somewhat, but I would consider splitting this up into multiple charts. I am not sure if it is even possible to expand the legend to show those hidden 81 entries. And double check that the long lat location corresponds correctly with the world map projection you are using, they seemed to move around when I changed the projection.

---

Comment: Thanks for your reply, that solution looks great but when I tried to run it i got the error:


<ipython-input-1-1b67e1532005>:9: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  df['featureType'] = df['featureType'].str.split(',')

Comment: I agree about the legend however, I think I may use another chart as a selection tool! The points do seem to move around correctly to match the map projection, or at least from what I can see!

Comment: @KierenSpittles That warning is more of a "heads up" that pandas column indexing might not do what we intended and we should double check. In this case it is fine, but I rewrote that section to do the indexing as we read in the data, which avoids the warning altogether. Please accept and upvote the answer if you find it helpful so that this question gets marked as resolved.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have accepted and upvoted (although i am new so Im not sure the upvote is shown?)